# Unlock and Lock My Raspberry from an ssh Connection

Tags: raspbian, ssh, screen

I have my RasPi connected to my TV and was wondering how I could lock and unlock the gui via SSH.

I disabled the autlogin on boot with purpose and I would like to be forced to connect an Keyboard for the Login.

When I tried google, I found the `xset s off` and `xset s on` commands but this seem to have no effect.

Also I installed `xscreensaver` but I am not sure how I can login in the beginning.

I am using the RP3 with Raspbian and Pixel.

Hope, some of you might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to kick a user who has a GUI session open, using SSH? In that case

```
sudo pkill -f lxsession
```

should do the trick. It will forcibly close the current session and display a new GUI login dialog.

If you want to prevent anyone from logging back on, you could (for example) unload the keyboard driver and disable HDMI after you have killed `lxsession`.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I am looking for. Do you also know how I start a new session logging another user in over ssh?

Comment: I guess that would be `sudo -u username startlxde`

Comment: yes that seems to do something but it throws an error

Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key** Message: main.vala:99: Session is LXDE
** Message: main.vala:100: DE is LXDE
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(lxsession:4454): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0

I tried `export DISPLAY=:0; sudo -u pi startlxde`

Comment: @MalteReddig You should be able to generate a new key with `xauth`, however this really begs for a separate question: comments are intentionally short and lack many formatting features.